# Google sheets - All my data is in column A; I want it spilt into 6 columns

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I wonder if someone can help me with this (I often come across this situation and every time I search for an answer and can't fine one - I'm amazed I seem to be the only one to have this problem :-)

I have all my data in column A, but I want it split into 6 columns

from this...

---

```
Eleanor Rigby
The Beatles
1
 
2:05

People Are Strange
The Doors
The Very Best Of The Doors
 
2:10

Road Movie To Berlin
They Might Be Giants
Flood
 
2:22

Mr Kiss Kiss Bang Bang
Shirley Bassey
Thunderball
 
2:14
```

to this...

---

```
|Eleanor Rigby          |The Beatles          |1                          | | |2:05
|People Are Strange     |The Doors            |The Very Best Of The Doors | | |2:10
|Road Movie To Berlin   |They Might Be Giants |Flood                      | | |2:22
|Mr Kiss Kiss Bang Bang |Shirley Bassey       |Thunderball                | | |2:14
```

(Some columns are unpopulated.)

Answer (score 0):

either MOD it or SKIP it:

C2:

```
=QUERY(A1:A, "skipping 6", )
```

D2:

```
=QUERY(A2:A, "skipping 6", )
```

E2:

```
=QUERY(A3:A, "skipping 6", )
```

etc.

[image]

---

MOD would be:

C2:

```
=FILTER(A1:A, MOD(ROW(A1:A)-1, 6)=0)
```

D2:

```
=FILTER(A1:A, MOD(ROW(A1:A)-2, 6)=0)
```

E2:

```
=FILTER(A1:A, MOD(ROW(A1:A)-3, 6)=0)
```

etc.

[image]

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Many thanks. I've been looking for a solution to this for years. I owe you one.